# bootstrap even grid rows

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I'm currently listing data in 3 columns.  The contents of these columns can vary in height and I've noticed that it creates an uneven design if the height isn't 100% the same as seen in this screenshot:

[image]

Ideally, I'd like for each of the rows to remain even so the rows remain even.  Here's the current CSS:

```
<span v-for="team in teamSet.teams">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        // vuejs templating code
    </div>
</span>
```

I haven't been able to come up with a way to accomplish this with VueJS and bootstrap.  Can someone offer any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option, and the best approach for what you are looking for, is using the flex display, you can get more info at this [flex guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Basically consists in setting the container with the following CSS:

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

Here is an example: [simple flex codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwyPNj)

Flex is very suitable and can handle many requirements

Answer (score -1):

Not knowing what vue.js is spitting out, I can only give an unspecific answer:

```
.container > .direct-child-element:nth-child(3n+1) {
    clear: both
}
```

".container" would be the wrapper to the columns and ".direct-child-element" represents the columns (direct children).

Explanation: the taller columns above prevents the columns below from continuing to "float over" because it's simply just in the way and clearing each row at the first element (selected by nth-child(3n+1)) makes it so the rows will always "clear" the above elements and float all the way over.

PS: The code snippet you provided is HTML not CSS :)